# Truncation styling not working within <a> tags but works for <div> and <p> tags

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to truncate the text that displays from an `<a>` tag but it isn't working.  I applied the styling to other tag styles and it did work (none of the examples I saw used an `<a>` tag either).  I was wondering if someone could explain to me why this is happening (I'm not the best at HTML/CSS) and help me get it working. Here is my code.

If it helps to know I'm also using .less.

CSS:

```
.blockTrunc{
    width: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a class="blockTrunc" href="#" >
    <i class="icon " ></i>{{{this.foo}}}: test length adder <span>{{this.bar}}-{{this.fizz}}</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't apply `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to `inline` elements. You can change the `a` to `display: inline-block;` and it should then work.

**CSS:**

```
.blockTrunc{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/z6cm4gcw/

Answer (score 2):

[**W3 text-overflow docs**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#text-overflow) states:

> **Applies to:**   block containers

So, you'll have make it a block container, either setting it's `display` property as a `inline-block` or `block`.

[**Updated JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/etgzfv0h/)

Answer (score 0):

i've resolved wrapping your "A" element with a DIV with the class you have used:

```
<div class="blockTrunc">
<a href="#" >
    <i class="icon " ></i>{{{this.foo}}}: test length adder <span>{{this.bar}}-{{this.fizz}}</span>
</a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z6cm4gcw/

Comment: Ok but OP asked about `<a>` tags - and specifically said "explain to me why this is happening"

Comment: Understood, but he specifically said `works for <div> and <p> tags`, just pointing it out since the answer seems incomplete.

Comment: Ok i understand, i only tried to resolve this easily (without css modifies)

Comment: But, is changing the Html structure really easier than adding a single css property?

Comment: @LcSalazar well i think yes (i mean only to WRAP an element).
change the css can compromise the entire site, I prefer to add a small piece of html css without dirtying the

Comment: But, adding a div (which is a `block` element), wouldn't create the same layout issues that turning the `<a>` to a `display: block` element?

Comment: @LcSalazar of course, but i wrap only THAT element, i don't want to change style for every ".blockTrunc" elements

It's hard, for me, to explain my idea (i don't know english, i'm practicing)